# Code Not Working For Other Senders

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am creating a log file (text) whenever an email is received with a subject containing specific values and moving the email to a specific folder. The code works on one email sender and does not work when another sender sends with the same subject. The intention is that anyone sending an email with similar subject should be handled by the code.

Below is the code in ThisOutlookSession.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set olInboxItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim olMailItem As MailItem
    Dim strAttachmentName As String

    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
        Set olMailItem = Item

        If olMailItem.Attachments.Count = 0 _
        And InStr(olMailItem.Subject, "Exception Noted at FTD") > 0 Then

           'Create LogFile to a network folder
            Dim strFile_Path As String

            strFile_Path = "\\10.53.66.30\cbd\Status\" & olMailItem.SenderName + "StaffLogfile.txt"
            Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
            Write #1, Format(olMailItem.ReceivedTime, "dd-mmm-yyyy | hh:mm | ") + olMailItem.SenderName + " | " + olMailItem.Subject
            Close #1

        End If

        'Move to Exception Folder
        Dim fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder

        If olMailItem.Attachments.Count = 0 _
        And InStr(olMailItem.Subject, "Exception Noted at FTD") > 0 Then
           Set fldr = Outlook.Session.Folders("Archives").Folders("Personal Folder").Folders("FTD").Folders("Exception Report")
                olMailItem.Move fldr
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: can you try running it without On Error Resume Next? are there errors?

Comment: no errors are coming at all. for one sender, it works perfectly but with another sender, it does not create the log file nor move the email to the intended folder, it just stays in the inbox.

Comment: Remove the misused On Error Resume Next whatever the outcome then try  And InStr(UCase(olMailItem.Subject), UCase("Exception Noted at FTD")) > 0 Then

Comment: @niton, I have disabled the On Error Resume Next and added your Ucase but still the issues persist, although it still works for same sender except for other senders.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for trying to help me out.  I have found the issue and this is now working perfectly for me.

Earlier version:

```
If olMailItem.Attachments.Count = 0 _
    And InStr(olMailItem.Subject, "Exception Noted at FTD") > 0 Then
```

Corrected version:

```
If InStr(olMailItem.Subject, "Exception Noted at FTD") > 0 Then
```

With this correction, the code now works for all incoming messages. I don't know why the attachment checking statement is causing the problem. Since I have mandated the staffs concerned to send the email without any attachment and instead put the content in the body itself, this would somehow resolve my issue. Again, thanks for the help.